# Выполнение функций циклично

Tags: qt

Возник вопрос от новичка. Хочу выполнять свои функции - читать и парсить файл. Написал код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);      
    MainWindow w;
    w.show(); 

    MyServer server;

    f1();
    f2();

    return a.exec();    
}
```

Когда выполняю этот код, функции срабатывают всего 1 раз, далее идет переход в exec, и все останавливается. При этом экземпляр класса MyServer(работает с сокетом) - работает и принимает данные, пишет их в файл. А мне нужно что бы они выполнялись циклично.

Как быть? Чувствую свои функции нужно оформить в класс и использовать его, но может есть какой другой способ?

Comment: Обернуть ваши функции в цикл?

Comment: Да. Там функции - прочесть файл, распарсить данные, вывести данные и обновить график. И они выполняются циклично, но при этом еще идет прием данных с сокета.

Comment: Ну так оберните, если да :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/network-broadcastsender-sender-cpp.html)

Нужно создать объект таймер, и в обработчике работать с сокетом.

Comment: Т.е. я могу создать несколько таймеров и в них, при наступлении срабатывания таймера, выполнять свои функции?

Comment: Конечно, с разными интервалами.

Comment: Если данные идут на сокет раз в 2 с, то таймер нужно запускать на 2с? Не будет потери данных? Данных 15 переменных, типа int.

Comment: Если функция успеет выполниться за 2 сек, ровно через 2 с после начала первой начнется снова.

Comment: А таймеры могут работать параллельно?

Comment: Да, только у каждого свой обработчик.

Comment: Спасибо большое! С таймером заработало!